# How to show all the top used tags (terms) from sites and site collections

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store, term-set

How to show all popular tags from site and site collection. I have used 'Tag Cloud Web part' and created terms in term store management. Created a list and added managed metadata column and added a new item with one particular term. But tag cloud web part not showing any data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s the default behavior in SharePoint Online.

Tags & Notes feature of SharePoint Online has been retired, so Tag Cloud web part in the web part gallery is still visible and enabled, but it will show up as blank when added to a page.

Check the article [SharePoint Online Tags & Notes feature retired](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-online-tags-notes-feature-retired-77851bd5-6d5e-42fe-9bf6-d7c17eeb771f)

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for the response. I have tried 'Popular Items' web part by applying filter on 'Tag' but am not able to see the results. Are there any workaround to show popular tags. ?